# HTML - collect data with php from a textfield out of the post <form>

Tags: php, html

HTML :

```
<script src="bilal.js"></script>    
<form action="action.php" method="post" id="Form1">
        <input type="text" name="otherData" value="xxx">
        <input type="hidden" name="nameExample" value="" id="nameExampleCopy">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

Username: <input type="text" name="nameExample" id="nameExampleOriginal">
```

and a JS code copies the value of an external input field to a hidden input field.

JS :

```
document.getElementById('Form1').addEventListener('submit', function () {
    var originalElement = document.getElementById('nameExampleOriginal');
    var hiddenElement = document.getElementById('nameExampleCopy');
    hiddenElement.value = originalElement.value;
});
```

action.php :

```
<?php
echo $_POST['otherData'];
print "\n";
echo $_POST['nameExample'];
?>
```

but i only get the "otherData" that inside the form and can't get the username , any way to do that ? and i heard about Sessions is it useful to use it here ? and how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting JS part in the same page..

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" id="Form1">
        <input type="text" name="otherData" value="xxx">
        <input type="hidden" name="nameExample" value="" id="nameExampleCopy">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

Username: <input type="text" name="nameExample" id="nameExampleOriginal">
<script>
document.getElementById('Form1').addEventListener('submit', function () {
    var originalElement = document.getElementById('nameExampleOriginal');
    var hiddenElement = document.getElementById('nameExampleCopy');
    hiddenElement.value = originalElement.value;
});
</script>
```